# ESRI/ArcGIS: "Error: Services Directory has been disabled."

Tags: javascript, geospatial, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

## *"Error: Services Directory has been disabled." (Error: 403)*

Hi,

I'm a first-time user of ESRI/ArcGIS API's. I've set up an account...etc... and have a Node server which gets an ESRI token and makes a request to an ESRI/ArcGIS services endpoint -- the VRP (Vehicle Routing Problem) service.

**I simply want to 'Enable' the "Services Directory" ... or whatever the language is in this case**.

I'm not trying to do anything advanced, just touch the service to get acquainted with the input & output -- very <s>simple</s> <s>straight-forward</s> basic stuff.

However, when I attempt this request, the response body is an HTML string (`200/ok`): `<b>Error: Services Directory has been disabled.</b>` I've searched (a lot) for a resolution, including from the following page:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/admin.html

Ironically enough (or maybe too much), I don't find anything on ESRI/ArcGIS -- OR -- even Stackoverflow about this matter -- even though it seems to be the first barrier to entry in using these services.

Take a look at the link above, if you will, and hopefully you can enlighten me on what its explaining -- namely, the `http://<host>:<port>/<instance>/admin` URI schema. It *seems* that I may need to host/install an Admin/Management server somewhere (?). I'm using my `localhost` (signed up for Free / Developer Package) right now -- do I need to deploy before I can install/config something? Is there a "*Enable Service 'X'*" in the ESRI Online portal / myesri?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are hitting the wrong url. What is the url(scheme) of your VRP (Vehicle Routing Problem) service you are trying to make request?

Comment: Actually, I was sending a `GET` request to the (synchronous) endpoint -- which needed to be a `POST`. Also, the parameters *must* be in the URL, it seems. After this, it was just some tweeking of the parameter values, and I was set. I'm currently successfully getting back a VRP solution -- and I plan on providing constructive feedback within this thread for others. THANK YOU for reaching out!

Answer (score 1):

Basically it seems that despite their doco.. Esri doesn't have the services directory activated on that url in their samples...

https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/ is where the service is now...

eg
[https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?f=json&text=Lesmurdie&maxSuggestions=6&token=\](https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?f=json&text=Lesmurdie&maxSuggestions=6&token=%5C)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you make a URL request to an arcGIS server. Only the server administrator can enable the services directory and as it is disabled you cannot make HTML requests to the get rest services.
[Here a link to what ESRI says](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//0154000005vv000000)